# What type of connectors do natural gas BBQs have and what's needed to modify existing stub-out?

Tags: gas, valve, natural-gas

I got a natural gas BBQ with a non-threaded connection at the hose. There is also a gas stub-out under my deck that has a valve that can be shifted back. Both are non-threaded and they don't mate.

1. Are natural gas BBQ hoses/connectors standardized and is the BBQ connector in the picture a standard one?
2. Are these stub-outs designed to attach/detach the BBQ when needed? (I do not want the BBQ installed/connected permanently). In such case, are connections established by threads or other mechanism (e.g. shifting back a valve and plugging in)?
3. Do these connectors have safety features that turn off when gas escapes too fast (i.e., when there is a leak or the BBQ is disconnected without closing valves)? I think propane BBQ have these.
4. What is the valve of the current stub out exactly?
5. How do I need to modify the stub-out to be able to plug in outdoor BBQs? (Note: I do not just want to fit it to the current one, the connection should be flexible for any BBQ I might purchase in the future)

[image]

Note: I know a shutoff valve will be required (and desired!) as well; I assume first is the shutoff valve and then the connector.

Comment: Unsolicited pedantry: Barbecue is a _cooking technique_. You have a _grill_. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The female quick-connect (stub-out) seems to be 3/8"

Your male disconnect (hose) seems to be 1/2"

Pick one and replace it.

My recommendation is to replace the quick-connect with a 1/2" version so that you can support higher BTU grills.

---

> Are natural gas BBQ hoses/connectors standardized and is the BBQ connector in the picture a standard one?

Yes

> Are these stub-outs designed to attach/detach the BBQ when needed?

Yes

> (I do not want the BBQ installed/connected permanently). In such case, are connections established by threads or other mechanism (e.g. shifting back a valve and plugging in)?

Threads are for permanent use. That quick-connect is for disconnecting when needed.

> Do these connectors have safety features that turn off when gas escapes too fast (i.e., when there is a leak or the BBQ is disconnected without closing valves)? I think propane BBQ have these.

No, at least it doesn't look like yours does. Excess gas-flow protection is needed inside the home where gas can actually build up.

> What is the valve of the current stub out exactly?

A quick-connect.

> How do I need to modify the stub-out to be able to plug in outdoor BBQs? (Note: I do not just want to fit it to the current one, the connection should be flexible for any BBQ I might purchase in the future)

You can either replace the female quick-connect with a 1/2" one or replace your grill hose with a 3/8" version.

Comment: "The great thing about standards is there are so many to choose from".  Don't pick one, change the smaller fitting on the pipe.  It's cheaper to change this than the whole BBQ hose, and you won't have a 3/8" constriction then.  And I suspect if you buy a 3/8" hose it won't fit your bbq, unless you buy one that's 3/8 on the QC end and 1/2 on the threaded end.  Just change the pipe fitting.

Comment: @jay613 I 100% agree but I did not want to assume OP has any comfort in modifying a gas line =)

Comment: @jay613 [Obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/927/)